# Using TextWatcher to calculate average between EditTexts

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with a project on android studio and i need your help. I have created a line with 3 `EditText` and one `Textview`. I want to write numbers on the `EditText` and calculate the average on the `Textview`. I also use a button to create a new line when i click it. I achieved the calculation on the first line but every time i try to calculate a line where the button created, i get no result. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private LinearLayout parentLinearLayout;
private BreakIterator resultsText;
EditText editText1;
EditText editText2;
EditText editText3;
TextView textViewResult;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    parentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text1);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text2);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text3);

    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_text_view);

    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(avg());
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(avg());

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    editText3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(avg());

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

private String avg() {
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int number3;
    if(editText1.getText().toString() != "" && editText1.getText().length() > 0) {
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number1 = 0;
    }
    if(editText2.getText().toString() != "" && editText2.getText().length() > 0) {
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number2 = 0;
    }
    if(editText3.getText().toString() != "" && editText3.getText().length() > 0) {
        number3 = Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number3 = 0;
    }

    return Integer.toString((number1 + number2 + number3)/3 );
}

public void onAddField(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
    // Add the new row before the add field button.
    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);


}

public void onDelete(View v) {
    parentLinearLayout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
}

}
```

And two .xml files:
activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlTable01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CCC"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#7CFC00"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#7CFC00"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Scoring List"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψωΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Examiner's Name"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.01"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Student's Name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="User Interface"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Functions"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="User Manual"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="AVG"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.35"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.01"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/word_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψωΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number_edit_text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number_edit_text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number_edit_text3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.15"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:onClick="onDelete" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/add_field_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#555"
        android:onClick="onAddField"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Add Field"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and field.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_weight="0.01">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number_edit_text1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number_edit_text2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number_edit_text3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number_text_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="2.15"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    android:onClick="onDelete" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you add new field layout to parent at time you need to implement required listener with reference to handle listener for multiple field layout.

Comment: Why don't you do it with RecyclerView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code for you:

```
public void onAddField(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
    ((EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text1)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_text_view)).setText(
                    avg(((EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text1)),
                            ((EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text2)),
                            ((EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text3))));            }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    ((EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text2)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_text_view)).setText(
                    avg(((EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text1)),
                            ((EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text2)),
                            ((EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text3))));
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    ((EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text3)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_text_view)).setText(
                    avg(((EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text1)),
                            ((EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text2)),
                            ((EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text3))));

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    // Add the new row before the add field button.
    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);


}

private String avg(EditText viewById, EditText viewById1, EditText viewById2) {
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int number3;
    if (viewById.getText().toString() != "" && viewById.getText().length() > 0) {
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(viewById.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number1 = 0;
    }
    if (viewById1.getText().toString() != "" && viewById1.getText().length() > 0) {
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(viewById1.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number2 = 0;
    }
    if (viewById2.getText().toString() != "" && viewById2.getText().length() > 0) {
        number3 = Integer.parseInt(viewById2.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number3 = 0;
    }

    return Integer.toString((number1 + number2 + number3) / 3);
}
```

It didn't worked because you didn't assigned any listeners to the fields.

Also, i would suggest you to use **RecyclerView** for the views that you are adding.

**Note**

`avg` function is new function, don't replace it with yours.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Well that was too fast and it works great! Thank you very much for your help! I will give a try to RecyclerView also :D

Comment: If you need help with that too, don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `TextWatcher` in new line edittexts also.Without add `textwatcher` you unable to find average for them

check the below code and I hope it's will help for you:

```
private String avg(EditText editText1,
                   EditText editText2,
                   EditText editText3) {
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int number3;
    if (editText1.getText().toString() != "" && editText1.getText().length() > 0) {
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number1 = 0;
    }
    if (editText2.getText().toString() != "" && editText2.getText().length() > 0) {
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number2 = 0;
    }
    if (editText3.getText().toString() != "" && editText3.getText().length() > 0) {
        number3 = Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number3 = 0;
    }

    return Integer.toString((number1 + number2 + number3) / 3);
}

private void addTextListeners(EditText editText1,
                              EditText editText2,
                              EditText editText3,
                              TextView textViewResult) {

    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(avg(editText1, editText2, editText3));
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(avg(editText1, editText2, editText3));

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    editText3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(avg(editText1, editText2, editText3));

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}

public void onAddField(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
    // Add the new row before the add field button.

    EditText editText1 = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text1);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text2);
    EditText editText3 = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text3);

    TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_text_view);
    addTextListeners(editText1, editText2, editText3, textViewResult);

    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
}
```

1) remove your text change listeners from on create and just call

```
 addTextListeners(editText1, editText2, editText3, textViewResult);
```

2)Updated your `onAddField(v)` and `avg()` with above methods